# PHPEXCEL rows layout

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I would like to write into a csv file using PHPEXCEL in the following format. The class in bold and a space after every class group.

[image: Format wanted]

But i have not been able to find a way to do it.

Here is what I could do.

[image: The format i have]

I generate the data from an sql and loop thought it. Here is my code

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY typeclass";
$query=mysql_query($sql);

$check='';
$i=1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{       
    if($row['class']!=$check)
    {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$i,$row['Class']);
        $check=$row['class'];
    }

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B' .$i,$row['Name']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C' .$i,$row['score']);

    $i++;                   
}
```

Can anyone help me get the desired output.

Comment: Note that writing as a CSV file will lose all formatting: a CSV file only supports data, not formatting. If you want formatting like bold, then you need to save in a file format that supports it such as xls (the Excel5 Writer) or xlsx (the Excel2007 Writer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to format a cell bold:

```
$styleArray = array('font' => array('bold' => true));

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

You can insert a new Row after inserting the class name.

```
 if($row['class']!=$check)
 {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$i,$row['Class']);
        $check=$row['class'];

        // Merge the cells with the class name
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A'.$i.':B'.$i);

        $i++; // Next Row
 }
```

Then you can put the name and score into column A and B:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A' .$i,$row['Name']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B' .$i,$row['score']);
```

That should do all the trick. For further questions using PHPEXCEL youre able to contact me via email.

By the way, poor Simon :(

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks. Now how would I add a space between the first group and the second?

Comment: at the beginning of the if statement ($row['class']!=$check) use if($bolSpace) $i++;
at the end of the if statement set $bolSpace = true;

This just adds a blank row, if its not the first class group.

Comment: what is ur email. I have a few more questions anout PHPEXCEL